# How come clicking my results doesn't take me to the href and unfocuses the text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text input that when I type in, people profiles come up that I can click and it is supposed to take me to their profile. The problem is that when I click on one of the people profiles from the results, it does not take me to their profile, it just ignores it because I set the result list to disappear on "blur" with the text input. Note that it DOES work (takes me to person's profile) if I remove the jquery that hides result list on text input blur. How come it is acting as if I am just clicking through the result link?

[image]

```
$(document).on('blur', '#student_search_b', function() 
{ 
    $("#student_search_results").hide();
});
```

.

```
<li id="student-search-bar">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="student_search_b" name="student_search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
    </form>
</li>

<!-- SEARCH RESULTS ARE STORED HERE -->
<div id="student_search_results"></div>
```

Comment: why are you setting the blur event on the document?

Comment: Good point lol. Let me fix that and i'll let you know.

Comment: post some more code about what you do coz your explanation isn't clear. Include html markup including a results list example

Comment: yezzz I have added the html markup for my search bar and results

Answer (score 0):

The blur event of the text box is fired first and hides the results pane before the click event on the link has a chance to fire.

If you absolutely want to keep the code in the blur event handler, you could delay its effect to give a chance to the click event on the link:

```
$('#student_search_b').blur(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { $("#student_search_results").hide(); }, 250);
});
```

A better solution would be to remove the blur event handler, and to hide the results pane in the click event handler of the div, which is processed after the click on one of its link controls:

```
$('#student_search_results').click(function () {
    $("#student_search_results").hide();
});
```

Comment: I would like to also be able to hide the results pane when the user tabs out of the text box or clicks outside of the results pane. To my knowledge, blur is needed to detect these occurrences?

Comment: I would think so. In that case, my first suggestion should work. You can adjust the delay as you want. You can set 1000 milliseconds first, and try with lower values afterwards.